# I am having problems creating a table i keep getting a ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis,

Tags: database, create-table

```sql
CREATE TABLE crimes (
crime_ID NUMBER(9,0),
criminal_ID NUMBER(6,0),
classification CHAR(1),
date_charged DATE DEAFULT SYSDATE,
status CHAR(2),
hearing_date DATE,
appeal_cut_date DATE,
);
```

I tried to add DATE DEAFULT SYDATE to hearing_date DATA and appleal_cut_data DATA but i keep getting the same code error in oracle apex.

Comment: Did you type DEFAULT or DEAFULT? The latter is a spelling mistake. You also have a `,` after your last `DATE`, which should not be there.

Comment: default.  And some how i managed to create the table by re writing it like this   CREATE TABLE crimes 

  (crime_id NUMBER(9), 

   criminal_id NUMBER(6), 

   classification CHAR(1), 

   date_charged DATE, 

   status CHAR(2), 

   hearing_date DATE, 

   appeal_cut_date DATE);  and it worked.

Comment: That has no defaults though.

Comment: This seems to indicate that you did indeed run it with the typo (because with DEFAULT instead of DEAFULT, it works just fine) ; https://dbfiddle.uk/-jhf2e8t